# WPF DataGrid Multi Column Sort not working when overriding OnSorting

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

So I've got a plain vanilla DataGrid, and it's bound against an ICollectionView.

I handle the DataGrid's Sorting event, and set e.Handled to true, to suppress it's default behaviour, for some reason once I try to clear my ICollectionView's SortDescriptions, and add two sort descriptions in place, it does absolutely nothing, it does not honour the secondary sort at all. Here is my simple code:

```
    private void DataGrid_OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        e.Handled = true;

        ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;


        var col = (DataContext as TeamModel).Players;

        col.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        col.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Id", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        col.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", direction));
    }
```

I just want to simply have a primary and secondary sort, but it seems to be doing nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .Refresh() of ICollectionView after you are finished editing the SortDescriptions

```
col.Refresh();
```

or alternatively you may use another method

```
using(col.DeferRefresh())
{
    col.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    col.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Id", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    col.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", direction));
}
```

Comment: I had the .Refresh as well, but it doesn't help either.